# changing colspan with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html-table

I have some third party code (wordpress plugin) that uses a table to display a shopping cart. The header has the colspan attribute set to 3 which keeps things in line. The problem is this looks horrible for small screens.

My solution was to display:none the product image with media queries(because it isn't needed on a small screen), but this destroys the alignment of the header because colspan now needs to be 2.

What I want to happen is that if the screen size is less than 560px wide, then we change the colspan from 3 to 2.

Research has led me to jquery but this is my first experience with it. I've sort of compiled the following code from this research, but I lack the knowledge to get it working.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 560){    
        $('.ec_cartitem_head_name').attr('colspan','2');
    }   
});
```

Any help getting this code working would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, but instead of `.attr`, try using `.prop`. Anyways, I tried to simulate your scenario as a demo with some extra coding to maintain the table.

The table is resizable (wrapping div actually), try reducing the width and see how the colspan is modified to 1 and increase the width to see how colspan is changed to 1.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#tableWrapper').resizable();

  $('#tableWrapper').resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 200) {
      $(this).find('.adjSpan').filter(function() {
        return !$(this).hasClass('adjusted');
      }).prop('colspan', 1).addClass('adjusted').parent().append("<td></td>");
    } else {
      $(this).find('.adjSpan.adjusted').prop('colspan', 2).removeClass('adjusted').next().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#tableWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
#tableWrapper table {
  width: 100%;
}
#tableWrapper table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css" />
Reduce the width to set the colspan to 1, increase to set it to 2. <br/>
<div id="tableWrapper" class="ui-widget-content">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="adjSpan" colspan="2">2+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Vega, thank you for the response! I am afraid I am a complete beginner and cannot make sense of how to apply the code for my needs. OOP isn't my thing (I'm okay at C++), so even making simple changes is a challenge!

Answer (score 0):

One approach, in compliant browsers (and given that you're using media queries already, you *should* be safe), is to use `window.matchMedia()`:

```
function toggleColspan () {
    $('.ec_cartitem_head_name').prop('colSpan', (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 560px)').matches ? 2 : 3));
}

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    toggleColspan();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleColspan();
    // whatever other code you might have
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/paz9xvfk/).

Note, though, that if you're showing/hiding (or including/removing) the `<img>` element based on the screen-size, that doesn't (expliticitly) remove the `<td>` that would otherwise be 'included' within the `colspan`.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Thank you for the response! The JS Fiddle works perfect, but I added the code to the site header and the body, nothing worked. The only thing I noticed was another plugin that uses jQuery starts it's lines with jQuery and not $. Please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: That's not a problem, have you tried replacing the `$` with `jQuery`?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! For learning's sake, why did that change matter?

Comment: Because `jQuery` is the name of the object that the library uses, but `$` is often used as a substitute/alias (for saving keystrokes when typing it out); also `$` is used by some other libraries as well, whereas `jQuery` is used *only* (so far as I'm aware) by jQuery itself.